# How to delete records by ids collection using ormlite

Tags: java, ormlite

I am trying to delete records by ids Collection using ormlite i dont know what is the problem, this is my code:

```
public <T> int deleteRecordsById(Class<T> klass, Collection<?> ids) throws SQLException {
    Dao<T, ?> mapper = DaoManager.createDao(connection, klass);
    mapper.deleteIds(ids); //here is the problem
}
```

This is the argument of deleteIds function:

deleteIds(Collection ids) 
Delete the objects that match the collection of ids from the database using an IN SQL clause.

i get an error:

The method deleteIds(Collection) in the type Dao is not applicable for the arguments (Collection)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem:

```
public <B> int deleteRecordsById(Class<T> klass, List<B> ids) throws SQLException {
    Dao<T, B> mapper = DaoManager.createDao(connection, klass);
    return mapper.deleteIds(ids);
```